# Let M and N be single-digit integers. If the product 2M5 x 13N is divisible by 36, how many ordered pairs (M,N) are possible?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

> Let M and N be single-digit integers. If the product 2M5 x 13N is divisible by 36, how many ordered pairs (M,N) are possible?
>
> <sub>-- [source](https://www.mbatious.com/topic/1012/quant-boosters-anubhav-sehgal-nmims-mumbai-set-1/28)</sub>

I tried it by reducing 36 into its positive factors (1,2,3,4,6,9,18,36) and then solving, but I got way too many pairs.
Can somebody help?

Comment: What do you mean by $2M5$ and $13N$? Are these concatenated numbers (two hundred something and five, one hundred and thirty something) or products (two times M times five, thirteen times N)?

Comment: Also, what is your source for these questions?

Comment: Or power $2M^5$?

Comment: To the close-voters: as the first answerer here, I think this is mathematically "interesting" enough not to be closed. It requires some knowledge of basic number theory (prime factorisations) if you want to do it in a quick neat way rather than brute-forcing all possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Yes, @Randal'Thor, 2M5 and 13N are concatenated numbers. And as for the source of these questions, I have a book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I'll assume here that the number $2M5$ and $13N$ are concatenated three-digit numbers rather than products, because if they are products then the question is trivial.*

Being divisible by 36 is equivalent to

> being divisible by *both* of its prime factors $4=2^2$ and $9=3^2$.

2. > $2M5$ is odd, so both factors of 2 must come from $13N$. That means $3N$ must be a multiple of 4, so either $N=2$ or $N=6$. In either of these cases, the product is definitely a multiple of 4 - it's an "if and only if" condition.
3. > If the product is divisible by 9, then either *both* factors are multiples of 3 (i.e. their digit sums are multiples of 3) or *one* of the two factors is a multiple of 9 (i.e. its digit sum is a multiple of 9).

   Let's consider the two cases from the first numbered point above:

   - > If $N=2$, then $132$ is divisible by 3 but not 9, so we need $2M5$ divisible by 3, i.e. $2+M+5$ divisible by 3, which means either $M=2$ or $M=5$ or $M=8$. In all of these cases, the product is definitely a multiple of 9.
   - > If $N=6$, then $136$ is not divisible by 3, so we need $2M5$ divisible by 9, i.e. $2+M+5$ divisible by 9, which means $M=2$. Again, in this case the product is definitely a multiple of 9.

So the possibilities for the pair $(M,N)$ are:

> $(2,2),(5,2),(8,2),(2,6)$ - **four** possibilities in all.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's nothing to do with "you" or "me" - don't take it personally. I don't like answers which use computers instead of elegant mathematics, but i don't go around downvoting or deleting them either (unless they're on questions tagged [tag:no-computers], which this isn't). On this site, we're commenting/voting on content not people, as you should know :-)

Comment: Just to balance the comment you decided to leave, nobody downvoted or deleted a question, or suggested the mutual voting you accused me of requesting. You could have deleted it with the others, but for some reason decided not to.

Answer (score 5):

Confirmation of the [answer from Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/84741/51581) using brute force with C - only 100 perms:

> ```
>  #include <stdio.h>
>  
>  int main(void)
>  {
>      for(int M = 0; M < 10; M++)
>          for(int N = 0; N < 10; N++)
>              if(((205 + 10 * M) * (130 + N)) % 36 == 0)
>                  printf("%d %d\n", M, N);
>  }
> ```
>
> 2 2
>  2 6
>  5 2
>  8 2